# How to disable QGIS asking for DB password

Tags: qgis

I open a QGIS project and I am prompted for underlying database password. For certain reasons I do not want to connect to underlying database (let's say I just want to change a certain stored local shape layer style) so I click "Cancel". However almost on every movement in the desktop application I am prompted with this dialog. How to turn it off for good?

[image]

Comment: Have you got a live layer that is trying to access the database? Have you tried hiding it or removing it?

Comment: Yes, I understand why this window pops-up. What I want is: if I am editing QGIS project file in a machine which does not have access to layer's database not to be prompted with this window every time I click on something in the GUI. Because I just want to do a few changes to certain layer's style and I do not need connection with database for that.

Comment: And does hiding the layer (unticking the box on the layer list) stop the prompting? It might be the best solution until the Qgis developers perhaps implement something.